# Create array of arrays from database query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ive got a table which consists of two fields called follower_id and followed_id. I need to create a query which creates an array of from each row and puts that in an overall array so that the end structure looks like:

```
"edges": [
    ["1", "2"],
    ["1", "3"],
    ["3", "4"],
    ["3", "5"]
  ]
```

so far I have

```
 def self.including_relationships
  result={}
  result["edges"] Relationship.all.each do |relationship|
    result[""]= Relationship.select(:follower_id.to_s,:follower_id.to_s)
  #the code here is called once for each user
  # user is accessible by 'user' variable
end
  result
end
```

but this produces:

```
 edges: [
"[4, 3, 3, 4]",
"[3, 4, 3, 4]"
]
```

Comment: This seems like a join table. You're not supposed to query those directly. Have you looked at HABTM or `has_many :through` constructs? See the [rails guide for associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) to build an array like:

```
Relationship.all.map { |r| [r.follower_id.to_s, r.followed_id.to_s] }
```

Comment: should be r.followed_id.to_s but otherwise worked. Cheers

Comment: In case, you see something missing in any answer, you can edit it. However, I fixed it to `r`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
relationships = Relationship.all.map { |r| [r.follower_id.to_s, followed_id.to_s] }

results = {"edges": relationships }
```

Comment: I get syntax errors- unexpected : and } (although seems balanced?)